# iTerm2 & Terminal show my Mac serial code

Tags: terminal, iterm

[image]

I had problems with colours not showing in iTerm2 for me. I tried a few fixes I found online which didn't work and now my serial number of my laptop is showing in iTerm & Terminal. Anyone know how to remove this?

Comment: If you shut down and restart - this could be temporary. If not, type `hostname`, did you or your network name your machine with your serial number? If so, do you want to change the name entirely or just that prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to modify something called the prompt or PS1.  You can see the current value by typing `echo $PS1` To get rid of the first part you don't like and leave only the user name type `export PS1="\u"`  If you want to persist the next time you open the terminal, you would write that line in ~/.bashrc   A detailed walk through is here http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/